# GitLab with local IP install hangs at logrotate

Tags: logrotate, gitlab, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying and failing to install GitLab (EE) onto an on-premises bare-metal server PC running Ubuntu Server 20.04. The server is intended to later have internet-facing access, but for now it needs to be internal LAN only, accessed by IP or hostname if possible. The PC is currently set up with a static internal IP via netplan. We do not have a domain name reserved for this server or an SSL certificate at the moment.

I have a working Git server set up on the machine with successful access via SSH and via HTTP (Apache2, then switched to Nginx). My goal is to set up GitLab on the machine running in parallel with the existing Git server.

After getting Nginx running correctly yesterday, I attempted to install GitLab through Omnibus, using the procedure described at the [official GitLab install page for Ubuntu](https://about.gitlab.com/install/#ubuntu), first the `curl` adding the repository, then running `EXTERNAL_URL="http://10.7.2.xxx" apt install gitlab-ee` (internal IP, but censored just in case). The process finished without errors, but when attempting to connect to the server with that URL, I only got a 403 from Nginx. I suspect this was due to Nginx already running previously for plain Git on `/srv/www/git`. I attempted to remove it with `apt remove gitlab-ee`, followed by deleting the the remaining directories at `/etc/gitlab`, `/var/opt/gitlab`, `/opt/gitlab`, and `/var/log/gitlab`. At the time I did not know that was the wrong way to uninstall GitLab.

This morning I attempted a reinstall. First I stopped and disabling Nginx with `systemctl`, backed up my config by moving it out of `/etc/nginx/enabled-sites` into my home directory, then uninstalling it with `apt remove nginx`. After a reboot and confirming neither it nor Apache2 were running, I attempted to reinstall GitLab with `apt install gitlab-ee` again. It finished unexpectedly quickly, as it appears its resources were still present on the system. Connecting from a browser failed completely, no connection at all.

I attempted a reinstall again, this time uninstalling GitLab fully with the following commands:

```
# gitlab-ctl uninstall
# gitlab-ctl cleanse
# gitlab-ctl remove-accounts
# dpkg -P gitlab-ee
```

Removing accounts hung for 10min with no output so I had to `^C` it. After removing it with `dpkg` I then removed the same four directories as before, though only `/opt/gitlab` and `/var/log/gitlab` remained.

After a supposedly clean uninstall, I rebooted and attempted what I thought to be a clean reinstall. It hung on `* ruby_block[wait for logrotate service socket] action run` endlessly, for over an hour. Research pointed to opening up another terminal and running the following commands while omnibus was hung:

```
# nohup /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/runsvdir-start &
# gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

This didn't work, `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` hung for 10 mins before I gave up, and Omnibus on the other terminal didn't continue. It wouldn't even respond to `^C`. I had to force a reboot from another session, and attempted a "clean" uninstall, reboot, and reinstall again.

Uninstall this time did not have any problems with `remove-accounts` ([Pastebin log, username, hostname, IP censored](https://pastebin.com/KZEeMvdK)). However, once again it hung at `logrotate`, for over an hour again, and again not responding to `^C`. [Pastebin output](https://pastebin.com/MDD1zJWX), [Pastebin log from /var/log/gitlab/reconfigure/1636492507.log](https://pastebin.com/sa38imMv).

What has not solved my problem:

- `systemctl start logrotate.service` (immediately stops/finishes, awaiting the timer), `logrotate.timer` (was already running). No response from Omnibus when starting either.
- Running `runsvdir-start` and `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` (see above)
- Running `gitlab-ctl tail` (throws `tail: cannot follow '-' by name`)
- `multi-user.target` is loaded and active, according to `systemctl -t target`.

All the other results I can find are related to specific aspects of GitLab failing, rather than the initial install. I'm stumped and I can't find anything else relevant. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

Last night I forced another `sudo reboot`, and this morning upon running an `apt upgrade` I was prompted by dpkg to run `dpkg --configure -a`, which resumed the installation and finished it, successfully. I am even able to connect to the IP through a browser and get a GitLab login page. I don't know why this worked now.

*While this did solve my particular instance of this problem, for posterity I'd like to keep this question open for now to try to understand why this problem occurred (hanging at logrotate twice), and why this solved it.* If anyone else comes across this problem, knowing why it happened would be much more helpful than a magic command that might or might not work and doesn't explain why. If anyone could help explain why this problem happened or why this command worked for me, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same situation. Helped me:

```
gitlab-ctl status
```

output:

```
run: logrotate: (pid 558) 114s; run: log: (pid 557) 114s
```

Then:

```
gitlab-ctl stop logrotate
```

output:

```
ok: **down**: logrotate: 1s, normally up
```

And then the command `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` completes without errors